# Delphi transparent proxy for a TCP connection

Tags: delphi, proxy, tcp, sockets

Anyone know of any examples of a TCP sockets proxy application written in Delphi? I am building a small broker application that needs to listen for socket connections on a given TCP port, read a XML data packet sent over the connection, serve the request via TCP to a server chosen from a pool of available back end servers, and deliver the resulting response back to the originating TCP connection.

I am very familiar with TCP and socket-level programming, but would prefer to find sample code as a starting point. If there is something available it would save considerable time and effort since I would not need to reinvent the wheel. I recall seeing a small TCP proxy written in Delphi back in 2003/2004, but seem to have lost track of the link.

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for a socks proxy implementation?  If not, then just start with a server (http would most likely be a good start) and build into it the ability to process your inbound XML data packet, and make the appropriate calls.  Something like the [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php) framework would make that a fairly simple project.  If you grab Synapse, get the latest version from SVN.  It supports all of the latest versions of Delphi.

There is a [httpproxy](http://synapse.ararat.cz/files/contrib/httpproxydemo.zip) demo for synapse available, that might help if your wanting to implement something more traditional.  A good starting http server [example](http://synapse.ararat.cz/files/contrib/webcam.zip) is also available.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a straightforward TCP socket implementation. The broker will actually sit between BizTalk and an ERP system so I know 100% the data is XML, but not framed as a HTTP request. I do use Synapse under D2009 and will have a look at the HTTP proxy. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

IPWorks from nSoftware should be considered as a commercial alternative to Synapse. They also have some Biztalk adapters available.

I've used both Synapse and IPWorks, and they are both quite good.  I haven't used the referenced BizTalk adapters.

[BizTalk Adapters](http://www.nsoftware.com/products/biztalk/)

[IPWorks](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/)

Comment: Naming a component suite doesn't really count as linking to sample code, I think...