# Delphi 2009/2010 HTTP Proxy Server Component

Tags: delphi, http, proxy

Can you advice me an HTTP/HTTPS proxy server component for Delphi 2009 or 2010 (i.e. it must support Unicode). I know about Indy, but maybe there are alternatives?

Comment: In your question it is not clear if you want a HTTP client component with proxy support, or a HTTP Proxy Server component

Comment: Sorry, I need proxy server component. Question fixed.

Comment: Question seems similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941087/delphi-transparent-proxy-for-a-tcp-connection

Comment: I think you would have to build it mostly yourself with ICS, but I think ICS is a firmer foundation than INDY, which I consider crap.